# styling multiple divs with same class name differently

Tags: html, css

i want to style div elements in code below differently without changing class names , in fact every element with class named "right" represent one side of a hollow rectangle , so i want every elemnt have the same width and height but different position(vertical horizental ...) .

i know that i can give different id or class name to each div element but i want to know if there is anyway to style elements with same class names differently??

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id='container'>
    <div class='right'></div>
    <div class='right'></div>
    <div class='right'></div>
    <div class='right'></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can use nth child, first-child, last-child, and sibling combinators.

Comment: Can you also paste you ‘right’ class code?

Comment: Why don't you add additional classes to each element? For example `<div class='right vertical'></div>` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.right:nth-child(1) {
        background: red;
 }
 .right:nth-child(2) {
        background: yellow;
 }
...
```

https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/sel_nth-child.asp

Answer (score 0):

Inside each div tag You can add a new div tag with different class name or id. It won't make any difference in your output.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#container{
      display: grid;
      grid-gap: 20px;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id='container'>
    <div class='right'>one</div>
    <div class='right'>two</div>
    <div class='right'>three</div>
    <div class='right'>four</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```